# multiple conditions in excel showing points

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to make multiple functions where it shows a certain point if..

multiple conditions in excel showing points

```
if A1 is bigger than 500 shows 0
if A1 is smaller than 500 but greater than 200 then shows 0.3
if A1 is smaller than 200 but greater than 100 then shows 0.6
if A1 is smaller than 100 then shows 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may handle this with a nested `IF` function:

```
=IF(A1>=500, 0, IF(A1>=200, 0.3, IF(A1>=100, 0.6, 1)))
```

Comment: sorry doesn't seem to be working as intended for the numbers inbetween, say between 200 and 500 then showing 0.3

Comment: `if A1 is smaller than 500 but greater than 200 then shows 0.3` ... is this not the requirement you gave us?  I tested my code in Excel and it looks fine.

Comment: yes, so say if i put in 300 it should show 0.3, but shows 0 instead? also say if i put in 150, it should show 0.6 but shows 1. Thanks

Comment: @qbone I have no idea what you are talking about.  I just tested your values and got the expected outputs.  Are you _certain_ that you copied my _exact_ formula?

Comment: sorry, looks like I had my cell on currency for some reason, and Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, when the smaller and the bigger values are overlapping, it is always a good idea to consider a lookup table. In your case, you are looking for 4 types of result:

- smaller than 100
- smaller than 200
- smaller than 500
- anything else, let's call it smaller than 999999999

Thus, you may build a table like this:

[image]

Now depending on the value in `G1`, using an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), you will get what you need:

```
=INDEX(A2:B5,MATCH(TRUE,A2:A5>G1,0),2)
```